# Нужна помощь с ООП

Tags: python

У меня есть функция

```
def deletestring():
    with open('File.txt', 'r') as file:  # open file
        string = file.read().splitlines()
        if len(string) >= 1:
            get_string = string[0]
            string.pop(0)
            print(get_string)
    with open('File.txt', 'r') as file:  # open file
        for element in string:
            file.write(element + '\n')
```

И вот у меня есть строка get_string которая пишется в консоль, вот эта функция у меня в файле other, мне нужно содержание строки get_string перенести в файл main, я уже час сижу, не могу понять как сделать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: with open('File.txt', 'w') as file:  # open file перепутал***

Comment: ООП подразумевает классы, где тут они у вас, или причем здесь ООП?

Comment: Ну я только учусь, и я не вижу разницы что бы я сделал класс или ту же функцию у меня она будет одна, и мне нужно решение, а про ооп указал ну что, оно немного связано т.к в другом файле же, как не как.

Comment: поставьте в конце функции `return get_string` а в main `string = deletestring()`

Comment: Не помогло, ошбика 
  File "C:\Users\JonxC\PycharmProjects\telegram\main.py", line 33, in user_text
    other.deletestring()
  File "C:\Users\JonxC\PycharmProjects\telegram\other.py", line 11, in deletestring
    return get_string
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'get_string' referenced before assignment

Comment: значит, у вас файл оказался пустой, и блок if не выполнялся. Дайте get_string до if или в else значение для этого случая

Comment: Всё заработало! Спасибо вам большое я не знаю как вас отблагодарить, у вас нету рядом с ником лайка, если знаете подскажите я поставлю лайк.